# AngularJS: pop up dialog from a route?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-routing

I have an admin CRUD interface utilizing AngularJS. Everything is fine except one problem: I want to have a pop up dialog for editing/creating item and I can't make route to don't replace the whole ng-view. How its done and is it possible? If not then can I somehow define alternative way of running route?

Comment: far too many unknowns from what little information is provided...create a **[plunker demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/gist:3510140)** that provides an overview of the situation

Answer (score 0):

If your ok with using GET parameters for the pop-up dialog you can set reloadOnSearch to false on that route.

Something like:

```
$routeProvider.when('/channel/:channelid', {templateUrl: 'channel.html', reloadOnSearch: false})
```

Take a look at the Angularjs docs for more information:
http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$route